# Is there any alternative to input type file for file upload now that Android 4.4 no longer supports is?

Tags: android, html, cordova

I know there are a couple of threads on this but none of them seem to have a solution.
I'm developing my final year project at the minute as an Android mobile application. One of my features was a file upload inside a HTML form in the in app browser of Phonegap project. However, since my phone upgraded to Android KitKat 4.4, it no longer works as apparently it's unsupported.
I tried http://www.script-tutorials.com/pure-html5-file-upload/ tutorial but it also fails to work inside the inapp browser?
Is there anything else or any other way I can try before I have to scrap this idea from my application?
I really don't want to as it's a key feature and I'm going to lose marks.
Thanks lots,
Paula

Answer (score 1):

You can try this I've read on the [jira bug comments](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-5294)

> Cesidio DiBenedetto added a comment - 28/Mar/14 01:27
>
> Hey all, I've been experiencing this issue as well so I wrote a
>   Cordova FileChooser plugin to a "band-aid" for the time being.
>   Basically, in Android 4.4(KitKat), as mentioned in previous comments,
>   the file dialog is not opened. However the onclick event is still
>   fired on  so you can call the FileChooser plugin to
>   open a file dialog and upon selection, you can set a variable that
>   contains the full path to the file. At this point, you can use the
>   FileTransfer plugin to upload to your server and hook into the
>   onprogress event to show progress. This plugin is mainly configured
>   for Android 4.4 so I would recommend to continue to use the native
>   file dialogs for earlier versions of Android. There might be issues
>   with the plugin as I have not fully tested all possible scenarios on
>   many devices, but I have installed it on a Nexus 5 and it worked fine.
>
> https://github.com/cdibened/filechooser